# No input file specified - Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter, when uploding my website the default controler/view displays fine. However when i try to open other pages it gives the following error

**"No input file specified."**

. What puzzles me is this works fine in localhost.

I have read in this forum about changing htaccess file but i have no clue which htaccess file to change and how.

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You change `.htaccess` that is in your root directory (where system, application folders are), edit it in any text editor and save it as `.htaccess`.

Example of `.htaccess` is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If you are aiming to remove index.php from your url please find `config.php` file in `application/config` folder and edit few lines as follows

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourdomainhere.com.uk.alien.org';


$config['index_page'] = ''; //make this blank
```

**EDIT**

> The .htaccess file must be in Unix LF only style. If you use Notepad or Wordpad and upload an .htaccess file in CR/LF style it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but still the same error message appears. I am hosting in godaddy...

Comment: Please see this [link](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips).

Comment: Ok... I tested in other web hosting server and it works fine... so i guess you are right about issue being with go daddy